# Equivalent definition of prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a ring. Say an ideal $\frak p$ is prime if $IJ\subset \mathfrak p\implies I\subset \mathfrak p\text{ or }J\subset \mathfrak p$.

I need to prove that this implies the stronger condition in which $I,J$ are assumed both *right* ideals, but I don't see how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ and $J$ are right ideals, $RJ$ and $RI$ are ideals, and $IRJ\subseteq IJ\subseteq P$. Since $P$ is two sided, $RIRJ\subseteq P$ also. By hypothesis, $RI$ or $RJ$ is contained in $P$, whence $I$ or $J$ is contained in $P$.

Comment: By "$RJ$ and $RI$ are ideals" do you mean they're two sided?

Comment: @Exterior Yes, that is what I mean.